# How to rebuild ISO removing file from its mounted image?

Tags: linux, rhel, iso, mkisofs

I built an ISO that contains, for example:

```
Directory listing of /
d---------   0    0    0            2048 Mar 19 2015 [     29 02]  .
d---------   0    0    0            2048 Mar 19 2015 [     29 02]  ..
d---------   0    0    0            4096 Mar 19 2015 [     32 02]  target-rpms
d---------   0    0    0            2048 Mar 19 2015 [     34 02]  vat
Directory listing of /target-rpms/
d---------   0    0    0            4096 Mar 19 2015 [     32 02]  .
d---------   0    0    0            2048 Mar 19 2015 [     29 02]  ..
----------   0    0    0        32435902 Mar 18 2015 [     85 00]  file1.rpm
----------   0    0    0         2055833 Mar 18 2015 [  15923 00]  file2.rpm
Directory listing of /vat/
d---------   0    0    0            2048 Mar 19 2015 [     44 02]  .
d---------   0    0    0            2048 Mar 19 2015 [     29 02]  ..
----------   0    0    0               0 Apr 20 2015 [  56633 00]  file1.txt
```

I would like to add/remove file from ISO mounted image, so I did:

```
  sudo mount -o loop,ro /full/path/to/file.iso /mounted/path
```

In order to add file I found this method:

```
mkdir /path/where/put/addedFile/vat/
cp prova.txt /path/where/put/addedFile/vat/prova.txt
mkisofs -o /tmp/test.iso -A test-1.0 -copyright 'Test' -joliet-long -RU
 -uid 0 -gid 0 -iso-level 4 /mounted/path /path/where/put/addedFile
```

that works, `mkisofs` merged file into directory and `test.iso` contains all desired files.

I need some help on how to create `test.iso` without, for example, `target-rpms/file2.rpm`.

I know that I can do it using this procedure:

```
mkdir /path/where/rebuildIso
cp -R /mounted/path /path/where/rebuildIso
rm /path/where/rebuildIso/target-rpms/file2.rpm
mkisofs -o /tmp/test.iso -A test-1.0 -copyright 'Test' -joliet-long -RU
 -uid 0 -gid 0 -iso-level 4 /path/where/rebuildIso
```

but, due to iso dimension, I would like to avoid `cp` command.

I'm using mkisofs 2.01 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) on Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 3 (Taroon Update 2)

Comment: Do you have the `-m` and/or `-exclude` option?

Comment: mkisofs-2.01 is from 2004, do  you really like to use such an outdated version today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact mkisofs 2.01 points to genisoimage:

```
$ mkisofs --version
mkisofs 2.01 is not what you see here. This line is only a fake for too clever
GUIs and other frontend applications. In fact, this program is:
genisoimage 1.1.11 (Linux)
```

From `man genisoimage` you can try the `-m` option:

```
-m glob
          Exclude files matching glob, a shell wildcard pattern, from being written to CD-ROM.  glob may match either the filename component or the full pathname.  This option may be used multiple times.  For example:

               genisoimage -o rom -m '*.o' -m core -m foobar

          would exclude all files ending in `.o', or called core or foobar from the image.  Note that if you had a directory called foobar, it too (and of course all its descendants) would be excluded.

   -exclude-list file
          A file containing a list of shell wildcards to be excluded.  See -m.
```

Comment: `genisoimage` in fact is a `mkisofs` from May 2004 with some Debian specific bugs added. Since `mkisofs` fixed dozens of bugs since then (in special bugs that caused structural bugs in the created filesystem image) and since `mkisofs` doubled it's features since then, it is not recommended to use that outdated and long dead `genisoimage`.

Answer (score -3):

An easier to remember way is to use the built in `find` (via libfind) seen in `mkisofs` versions since 12 years. So in case you did update your OS installation since summer 2006, you could use e.g.:

```
mkisofs -o /tmp/test.iso -R -find  /mounted/path ! -name '*.rpm'  -chown root -chgrp root
```

If you like to merge more than one source path, add more paths directly past `-find`.

If you like to play with the destination path, check the `-graft-points` option that works with the built in `find` as well.

See man page at: http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man8/mkisofs.8.html